# execute python script by calling only name in venv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that and would like it to be run by just typing its name:-

First line of my code has this as the shebang:

```
(venv) root@c3-redsuren-vm01:~/my-project/find_wwn_dir# cat bro_cisco_main.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import paramiko
import sys


(venv) root@c3-redsuren-vm01:~/my-project/find_wwn_dir# ls
bro_cisco_main.py  zones_list.txt

(venv) root@c3-redsuren-vm01:~/my-project/find_wwn_dir# ls
bro_cisco_main.py  zones_list.txt


(venv) root@c3-redsuren-vm01:~/my-project/find_wwn_dir# whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3.7-config /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python3.5 /etc/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.8-config /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.7 /usr/include/python3.7m /usr/share/python3 /root/my-project/venv/bin/python3 /root/my-project/venv/bin/python3.8 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
(venv) root@c3-redsuren-vm01:~/my-project/find_wwn_dir#
(venv) root@c3-redsuren-vm01:~/my-project/find_wwn_dir# whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3.7-config /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python3.5 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python /usr/local/bin/python3.8-config /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.7 /usr/include/python3.7m /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /root/my-project/venv/bin/python3.8 /root/my-project/venv/bin/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz /usr/src/Python-3.8.2/python
```

I get confused with this PATH variable and setting.. Please help me understand.
I would like to execute my script by just entering its name:- bro_cisco_main.py or bro_cisco_main

Is it possible?

Thank you all!

Comment: In linux/unix/mac type systems you can use a shebang line like `#!/usr/bin/python3.7` as the first line of the python script. In this case you don't need to have a `.py` extension, but you do need to have the executable bit on, you can use chmod like `chmod +x bro_cisco_main.py` to turn it on.

Comment: thanks @AndrewAllaire i removed the .py and was able to run like:- ./bro_cisco_main Two questions. Q1. Just because the code has shebang enabled the code to run with just the name? And in which cases should be give the .py extenstion. Q2: Is it possible to just use bro_cisco_main instead of appending with ./

Comment: Provided the file is marked as executable in permissions linux shells will look to see if the first line is a shebang line to see how to run the file. This does not just work for python, for example it is common to see `#!/bin/bash` for files that contain bash shell script. The name of the file does not matter for calling it. Also many editors recognize the shebang line too, at least the ones I use do, so that a file with a python shebang line will be displayed with python syntax color highlighting and such.